# Email couldn't send to Ubuntu email server

Tags: server, thunderbird, email, postfix

I have setup an email server at ubuntu. It was working fine. But last time when I send an email to my email server (myownemailid@mydomain.com) from my yahoo email, I get the following error message at yahoo email.

```
152.128.242.58 failed after I sent the message.
Remote host said: 552 5.3.4 Error: message file too big
```

I could understand that in my email server there is not enough memory space. But I am very new to linux servers. I don't know how to fix this problem at my email server.

Comment: It would help if you said what exactly smtp server you use. My guess is Postfix - so have a look at message_size_limit and also mailbox_size_limit values and set them as required/wanted.

Comment: And of course spend some time reading Postfix manuals :)

Answer (score 2):

Most email systems place a limit on the size of emails, and many times that limit is exceeded by email attachments. 10G is a typical limit. The error can come from your email server, or Yahoo's email server.

Assuming that you're running Postfix as your mail server, in terminal, go to /etc/postfix, and edit main.cf. Look for a line like mailbox_size_limit =, and message_size_limit=. These set limits for your email server. Zero means unlimited.

Or, using the `postconf -d` command in terminal will show your current settings. `postconf -d | grep -i size` will show the parameters that you're interested in. In my config (not a server), the defaults are:

```
mailbox_size_limit = 51200000
message_size_limit = 10240000
```

`postconf -e 'message_size_limit = 10240000'` sets it to 10G. Set it to something higher, if you wish.

You'll need to restart Postfix after changing these settings.

Comment: I checked that file. It says, mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824 (1 GB). Shall I raise this memory to 2 GB?

Comment: Please see my answer update. Cheers, Al

Comment: Great to see the one solution what you have suggested. But I think I could delete some older emails and put the deleted email into the archive and save it to another disk? How can I do this?

Comment: I changed message_size_limit = 20480000 to 30480000 and mailbox_size_limit = 1073741824 to 2073741824 and reloaded postfix using the command 'postfix reload'. But still, I am not able to receive any email from Yahoo or Gmail and Internally.

Comment: Even I deleted some Junk emails from my friend's emails who have an email account on my server.

Comment: **Any** email, or ones with large attachments? Same or different recipients? Same error message about "message file too big"? I'd reset your size limits back to Postfix default, by commenting out those two lines in main.cf, and reloading postfix. Then use the `postfix -d|grep size` to see what they were set to. Then try the mail again. Cheers, Al

Comment: I comment out that two line. But still, I couldn't receive the emails. I checked the result of the command 'postfix -d|grep size'. It shows, mailbox_size_limit = 51200000 and
message_size_limit = 10240000
I posted same question here. http://serverfault.com/questions/811822/sending-email-in-postfix

Comment: What about a different recipient? Does that have the same problem? Cheers, Al

Comment: Yes. I tried to send my friend's email. It has the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47576/discussion-between-smith-dwayne-and-heynnema).

Comment: What may have happened is that originally when the mailbox_size was set so high (1,073,741,824) it caused a problem? My expertise is limited any further, but I'd love to hear the final outcome. Cheers, Al